# Self-join with "and" in on clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have this query:

```
SELECT 
      A.ID
    , case WHEN B.Col2 IS NULL  then 0 else b.Col2 end AS Newcol
FROM TableA as A
LEFT join TableA as B
    on A.ID = B.ID and B.col1 = 'Something'
```

ID is unique.

I don't think it is nessasary to do a join above and we can optain the same result simply by using a `case when` in the `select`:

```
SELECT 
      ID
    , case WHEN Col1 != 'Something'  then 0 else Col2 end AS Newcol
FROM TableA
```

Comment: You would need to use a subquery in your second attempt to achieve a **similar** result. Note the word **similar**. In a 1:M relationship, a join can generate multiple rows for a given value of A.ID. A subquery MUST generate a scalar (single) value.

Comment: And i'll point out that you have no WHERE clause so your link is not particularly relevant to the actual question.

Comment: @SMor thanks, yes the ID here is unique. But I still don't understand.

Comment: I gave you the relevant information. Set up (or find) some tables that have a 1:M relationship between them. E.g., Orders and OrderDetails. Then adapt your query to those tables. Experiment is the best way to learn.

Comment: @SMor. But I would like to create a temp table and use where...

Comment: @SMor subquery where? In select or in a where condition. I I guess you mean a correlated subquery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to build a demo table that contains each possible type of value in your table so you can check the results of your rewrite are the same.

Your rewrite won't return the same result if `Col1 is null` or if `col1 ='Something' and col2 is null`.
You can however do:

```
SELECT 
      A.ID
    , case WHEN (a.col1 <> 'Something' or a.col1 is null or a.col2 is null) then 0 else a.col2 end AS Newcol
FROM TableA as A
```

OR (more simply)

```
SELECT 
      A.ID
    , case WHEN a.col1 = 'Something'  then coalesce(a.Col2,0) else 0 end AS Newcol
FROM TableA as A
```

(of course I'm assuming that ID is the primary key of your table, I don't think I've ever come across a table with an ID column where it wasn't)

Comment: But they don't give the same result

Comment: Can you provide the values of col1 and col2 that don't match up?

Comment: Result sets look similar, but one has almost twice as many rows

Comment: The problem is that th ID is not unique...

Comment: In your post you said "ID is unique.". If it's not then you have two problems - you need to be able to base the logic on the value of col1 of a different row (using analytics) and you need to return more rows - which you can't do without a join or something like union.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
select id, case when col1='Something' or col2 is null then 0 else col2 end
from TableA a;
```

Comment: This does not seem to Include the left-join. The ID in the first situation is from the first table. We will filter those rows totally in a where clause like that.

Comment: But what about the predicate with col1 = 'something'

Comment: In the first query, col1='something' doesn't do anything.  It's applied on the LEFT of the join and col1 is not referenced anywhere else.

Comment: I think the col1 = 'something is there to put NULLs in col2 which is then is referenced in the case when in the select

Comment: But actually the other answer also has if col2 is null. I think he is right if we compare the original query because col2 can start with being null and it can become null because of the way the join is.